# nGinx and PHP-FPM downloads index.php

Tags: php, nginx

I have the following configuration to listen on port 80, but redirect to https. Then, to route everything through the index.php file, however, when I go to a page it just downloads the index.php file or shows `403 forbidden` on the homepage.

Any ideas?

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www.mydomain.com mydomain.com;
    rewrite ^ https://$server_name$request_uri? permanent;
}

server {
    listen 443;
    server_name www.mydomain.com;
    root /var/www/mydomain/public;

    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate mydomain.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key mydomain.key;
    ssl_session_timeout 5m;
    ssl_protocols SSLv3 TLSv1;
    ssl_ciphers ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT56:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:+LOW:+SSLv3:+EXP;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    location / {
        if (!-e $request_filename){
            rewrite \.(jpeg|jpg|gif|png)$ /public/404.php break;
        }
        if (!-e $request_filename){
            rewrite ^(.*)$ /index.php break;
        }
    }

    location ~ \.php {
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index /index.php;

        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;

        fastcgi_split_path_info       ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO       $fastcgi_path_info;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    }

    location ~* ^/(css|img|js|flv|swf|download)/(.+)$ {
        root /var/www/mydomain/public;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is serving the file of off 127.0.0.1:9000?

Comment: Also try to remove the `/` in `fastcgi_index /index.php`

Answer (score 0):

The `rewrite/break` causes the rewritten URI to be processed in the same location (`location /`) rather than the `location ~ \.php`. See [rewrite](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite) documentation.

The `location /` block looks rather strange with two identical `if` blocks.

You might consider splitting it into two blocks:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri /index.php;
}

location ~ \.(jpeg|jpg|gif|png)$ {
    try_files $uri /public/404.php;
}
```

If `/public/404.php` is your default handler for all 404 errors, you could use an `error_page` directive instead:

```
error_page 404 /public/404.php;

location / {
    try_files $uri /index.php;
}

location ~ \.(jpeg|jpg|gif|png)$ {
    try_files $uri =404;
}
```

See the [location](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location), [try_files](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files) and [error_page](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#error_page) documentation for more.